# My web service returns a struct, how will behind code know what it is?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

To avoid web service's problem of not being able to pass complex objects like dictionaries and trees, I created a small struct inside the class with a few values fields. However, the web service is in a seperate project in the solution and I'm unsure how the behind code that calls the webService function would know what the struct is. Should I copy the struct to the behind code file? Can I import it?

Here's a small example:

```
namespace mYWebService{

 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
  struct TreeData
    {
    private readonly string text;
    private readonly string parent;
    private string val;

    public TreeData (string Text, string Parent)
    {
        this.text = Text;
        this.parent = Parent;
        this.val = "";
    }

         public TreeData (string Text, string Parent, string Value)
    {
        this.text = Text;
        this.parent = Parent;
        this.val = Value;
    }


    public string Text { get { return text; } }
    public string Parent { get { return parent; } }
    public string Value { get { return val; } }

}


[WebMethod]`
 public TreeData getTree(){
      TreeData myTree = new TreeData("1","2","3");
       return myTree;
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the binding in the client code, all necessary complex data types will get created automatically, because they are described in the service's metadata. However, you should rather use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx) these days providing there's no hard requirement to use the old-fashioned .NET 2.0 web services (i.e. the `WebService` class).

Answer (score 0):

You will have a hard time compiling this because you are exposing a private struct in a public method. In the very least, the struct must be made public. I also recommend that you put your struct outside of the class, since inner classes / structs /etc is bad practice (this is my personal opinion, however you do not see them used much in e.g. the .net framework, indicating that Microsoft doesn't like them much either).

Keep in mind that web services are distributed by nature, thus you should not have to rely on references to the class directly. This is a SOAP service (I think), and the framework will expose the metadata of the service. This metadata can be used by Visual Studio to auto generate a proxy client which can be used to call the service.

Here's a simple way to set up a proxy:

1. Start the web service project executable (not in debug mode,  you will still need to be able to use Visual Studio for the next steps)
2. Select the project where your web service client (the code that calls the service) is located and add a **service reference**
3. This will open a dialog where you can enter the service endpoint (url). Enter the endpoint where the service is running, and you should be able to select in this dialog
4. Once the reference is added, some autogenerated proxy code should be generated for you. This will give you access to your Method.

Finally I do agree with Ondrej Tucny that you should look into WCF instead